# How can I reference a .NET type when it is passed in as a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a dll with an API provided by a vendor. They use a "type" to give mnemonic values to an integer;

```
ele.dog = 1
ele.cat = 2
etc.
```

I can from within the module reference ele.dog when I need a 1, 2 for cat, etc.

```
dim myEle As TheirClass.ele = ele.dog
```

However I would like to be able to translate a string variable from "dog" to "1". What is the syntax to do this?

The reason is, I need to pass back to their class the "1" and all I have is dog.

Comment: It sounds like they are using an `enum`, either explicitly or synthetically.  `Enum` has a parsing mechanism if it's truly an `Enum`, otherwise you'll need to use reflection.

Comment: Where did `"dog"` as a string var come from?   `ele.dog` is not a string

Comment: "dog" is coming from an external datasource. Yes TheirClass.ele is an enum, I will try to find docs on enum parsing.

Comment: If `dog` is an enum constant you can just convert it to an integer: `Convert.ToInt32(ele.dog)` or dynamically: `Convert.ToInt32(myEle)`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comments by #DStanley, I looked up parsing. The equivalent to;

```
dim myEle As TheirClass.ele = ele.dog
```

is

```
myVar = "dog"
dim myEle as TheirClass.ele = [Enum].Parse(GetType(TheirClass.ele), myVar)
```

At least this syntax doesn't give any errors.

It also has the added benefit of doing what I need as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Type.GetType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) (or possibly [Assembly.GetType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx), using the vendor's assembly) to get an instance of `Type` from the fully qualified typename. From there, you can use the various reflection APIs to create an instance of that type (such as [Type.GetConstructor()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Once you have an instance of that class, you can cast the object to the actual type that you know it is and use it as you normally would.